# Privacy Statement Windows 8 Charm Settings

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

My Windows Store App certification failed and the note given to me by the tester is that:

> "The app has declared access to network capabilities and no privacy
>   statement was provided in the Windows Settings Charm".

Can Somebody give me the exact code to solve this problem.

Comment: Sharing some of the code you already have will help others help you. BTW the error message makes it pretty clear that what you have to do is provide a privacy statement, which makes me think if the should be "How to provide a privacy statement to ..."

Comment: Here is your answer: http://blog.hfarazm.com/adding-privacy-policy/#.UyHs__mSwf0

Comment: Here is an article documenting the privacy certification failure. In short, uncheck the Internet (Client) capability in your app manifest if you aren't using the network, and if you are, the article tells what you need in a privacy policy, where to surface the privacy policy, and links to sample code.

Answer (score 27):

In your base page, (or individual page if you want it only on one), you can define the settings like this:

```
SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += SettingsCommandsRequested;

private void SettingsCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    //use "new Guid()" instead of string "privacy" if you're experiencing an exception
    var privacyStatement = new SettingsCommand("privacy", "Privacy Statement", 
            async x => await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://some-url.com")));

    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Clear();
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(privacyStatement);
}
```

Obviously in this example, we had the privacy policy link to an external page, however you can modify the code to open up a separate page within the app if you want.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's by far the quickest solution I've seen.

Comment: This throws a warning. For those of us that treat all warnings as errors, add "async" and "await" as follows: async x => await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(...)

Comment: You're absolutely right @Paul, I've modified the answer and added async/await in.

Comment: In Win8.1 I had to change the code as follows:

            SettingsCommand privacyStatement = new SettingsCommand(new Guid(), "Privacy Policy", async (handler) =>
            {
                await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/privacy"));
            });

            args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Clear();
            args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(privacyStatement);

Comment: @Hyndrix, you shouldn't have to create a Guid for the settingsCommandId parameter unless there's a chance in your code of adding two settings with the same ID

Comment: If I do not pass a Guid as parameter then I get a reflection exception during runtime (Windows 8.1). Maybe this has changed with from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1.

Comment: That's strange, I'm able to use the string "privacy" in Windows 8.1 with no exception, warning, etc.

Comment: In one my app I used the string "privacy", but a new app somehow doesn't want to work this way, new Guid() has solved my problem. Yet, first app is still working ok with the string. It's a kind of magic

Answer (score 3):

it looks like you have not included a privacy policy with your application. This is a [requirement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx#acr_4_1) in the windows store Check this [link](http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/your-app-needs-a-privacy-policy-in-the-windows-store/) out for more [information](http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/your-app-needs-a-privacy-policy-in-the-windows-store/).

Comment: Doesn't help: the link only says you have to add it, doesn't give any code on how to do that.