# How do I add my privacy policy link to the Windows Settings charm with Unity?

Tags: windows-8, unity-game-engine, windows-store

Windows Store rule 4.1.1 mandate that:

> You must provide access to your privacy policy in the Description page
>   of your app, as well as in the app’s settings as displayed in the
>   Windows Settings charm.

The Description page is easy, since when you setup your app in the store there's a field where you can enter the URL.

However I'm a bit clueless about how to add this entry in the Windows Setting charm in a Unity project. I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13055570/207655) answer but that assumes you are in full control and knowledge of your Windows Store app, while I'm just exporting from Unity, so I've no clue on where I would put that code.

So, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin [prime31/MetroEssentials](http://prime31.com/docs#winEssentials) has the function `registerSettingsCommand`, which allows you to do just that.

```
// Registers a settings item with an associated message that will be displaed in a popup when clicked
public static void registerSettingsCommand( string title, string message )

// Registers a settings item with an action. When the settings item is clicked the action will be called.
public static void registerSettingsCommand( string title, Action onActivated )
```

Answer (score 1):

Unity is exporting the game as JS or C#.

So have a look to these samples http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples. In these samples, there are a few Setting Charm screnios that you can use in your application.

But remember that, you should add setting charm after export the game.